# Seaborn jointplot+scatterplot is not showing full grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I'm using seaborn [joinplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) and [scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) to produce this type of plots:

[image]

My problem is that is not showing the full grid. I have marked the missing parts (that should work as a border).

The code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': X, 'col2':Y})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': X_main_map, 'col2':Y_main_map})

graph = sns.jointplot(data = df1,x="col1", y="col2",kind="scatter",s=2,color='darkred',marginal_kws={"bins":100,"color":"darkred"},marginal_ticks = True)
graph2 = sns.scatterplot(data = df2, x = "col1",y="col2", s=1,ax=graph.ax_joint)

graph2.set(xticklabels=[])
graph2.set(xlabel=None)
graph2.tick_params(left=False)  # remove the ticks

graph2.set(yticklabels=[])
graph2.set(ylabel=None)
graph2.tick_params(bottom=False)  # remove the ticks

graph2.set(ylim=(-12,20),xlim=(-10,13))
```

Comment: Maybe `graph.ax_marg_y.spines['right'].set_visible(True)` and  `graph.ax_marg_x.spines['top'].set_visible(True)` work for you?